# Data Dictionary do SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá, venho da cultura Oracle e quero aprender um pouco de SQL Server, estou com dificuldade de encontrar o dicionário de dados do SQL Server, já procurei em outros fóruns e não achei nada.

No Oracle temos um dicionário de dados que mostra todas as opções de visões do sistema, como por exemplo qual visão lista todas as tabelas do banco, qual visão lista todos os usuários, qual visão lista todas as *contraints* do banco etc.. e normalmente quando eu não sei o nome da visão eu faço um (`select table_name from dictionary where table_name like '%palavra_chave_aqui%'`) e eu acabo encontrando.

Qual o equivalente no SQL Server para eu listar todas as visões do sistema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *No Oracle temos um dicionário de dados que mostra todas as opções de visões do sistema, (...)
>   Qual o equivalente no SQL Server para listar todas as visões do sistema?*

Essa forma é uma implementação particular do Oracle Database.

Como consta em verbete da Wikipedia, “*Em bancos de dados relacionais o esquema de informações ([information_schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)) é um conjunto padrão ANSI de exibições somente leitura que fornecem informações sobre todas as tabelas, exibições, colunas e procedimentos em um banco de dados*”. O SQL Server permite obter metadados segundo esse padrão.

Cada banco de dados no SQL Server contém o seu próprio esquema de informações, denominado INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Uma forma de obter os metadados é

```
SELECT ...
  from bancodedados.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.objeto
  where ...
```

Os objetos disponíveis segundo o padrão ISO estão detalhados na documentação do SQL Server, iniciando por [System Information Schema Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql). Por exemplo, para listar as tabelas de um banco de dados há o objeto [TABLES](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql).

Além do SQL Server há outros gerenciadores de bancos de dados que permitem a obtenção dos metadados pelo mesmo método, como  MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL etc.

Há outras formas de se obter os metadados no SQL Server, inclusive com mais informações, mas como introdução me parece que o uso de INFORMATION_SCHEMA será suficiente. Entretanto, caso tenha interesse em aprofundar nos metadados do SQL Server, encontrará documentação a respeito em [System Catalog Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/catalog-views-transact-sql).

Artigos:

- [What is a SQL Server Data Dictionary?](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-a-data-dictionary/)
- [SQL Server System Views: The Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-system-views-the-basics/)